# Assumptions in proving convergence of Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD)?

Tags: variance, random-variable, expected-value

Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a random vector. Then $\text{Var}(v)= \mathbb{E}[(v-\mathbb{E}[v])(v-\mathbb{E}[v])^{\top}]$.

[On page 4 of analysis of SGD](https://raghumeka.github.io/CS289ML/gdnotes.pdf) the writer defines $\text{Var}(v) = \mathbb{E}[\|v\|^2]-\|\mathbb{E}[v]\|^2$, which is pretty similar to the variance of random variable. I was wondering if this definition can be linked to the vector one? If so, please do it regorously.